# Can't delete old winsxs on another drive

Tags: windows-10, permissions

I reinstalled Windows and my old OS drive is now the G drive, unused. I want to free up space, so I tried deleting G:\Windows\winsxs and it gave me a permission error. How can I delete this? I am an admin and I'm running explorer in admin mode.

[image]

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially play with the permissions by taking ownership and propagating down through the folder hierarchy, but that could be a lengthy process.

When faced with similar circumstances and I am absolutely *certain* it is something I want to delete, I typically boot the computer using one of the free Linux Live disc/USB distros so that it bypasses NTFS permissions.  Something to consider.

Comment: I already have permission which is strange. `MY-PC-NAME\Administrators` has full rights.

Comment: Based on the error message, your new Administrator user, isn't in the ACL list nor is it the owner of the folder.

Comment: Your admin group and user would have a different unique ID. As others have said it would be easier to boot a linux live cd and delete that folder there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the freeware application NTFSAccess to set permissions - works where all other suggestions fail.It can be downloaded from here https://www.zeus-software.com/downloads/ntfsaccess.
Run the application,and browse to the folder Windows\WinSxS.By default both options Set Folder Owner and Set folder full access rights are selected, so then Grant - the process will take a while due to the size of the folder. On completion, the folder can be deleted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).